# Java String split result

Tags: java, string, split

I don't understand why this is getting an output of 3:

```
String[] split = "name:john;;sex:m;;".split(";");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split) + " size " + split.length);
```

I have read Oracle documentation and I still wihout getting why is 3.

Why the output is:

```
[name:john, , sex:m] size 3
```

Where is taking the ' ' (the second on the list), and also why the ";;" at the end is not in the output.

Comment: Nothing is. You split on `;`, so that emptiness between the `;;` is whats taking it. Split on `;;`

Comment: And from the Javadoc `Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array. `

Answer (score 3):

Documentation says

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

`split(";")` will get strings from before, between, and after each single semicolon. So your `split` array would theoretically be `{"name:john","","sex:m","",""}` at some point in the operation. However, `split()` removes trailing empty strings, so you actually get `{"name:john","","sex:m"}`.

As to why you don't have a terminal semicolons being printed, is because you split over each individual semicolon without a limit. The `limit` is length of the resulting array.

You can often fix internal empty strings by using the proper `regex` for multiple characters. You may want to check `split(";++")`. If you want the terminal semicolons you need to set a limit `split(";++",2)`.

Comment: @DanielHernández The documentation for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int- should explain it, and the link their describes all regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Arrays.toString` is representing your `split` array with space characters, instead of what it would actually be in the array of Strings returned by `String.split`, which is the empty string `""`. The final two semicolons on the end are not in the output because `String.split` only inserts the empty strings into its array where the delimiter you specify occurs within the string, not after it ends.

Comment: Yes, it is , I have printed those in for-each and it is empty ! nice eye

Comment: It looks like ... but "The final two semicolons on the end are not in the output because String.split only inserts the empty strings into its array where the delimiter you specify occurs within the string, not after it ends." That is the part I dont from the Oracle documentation

Answer (score 0):

The `''` is from the two semicolons that you put in between `name:john` and `sex:m`. The fact that they are not at the end is because java ignores empty strings at the end of a list.

Comment: Java doesn't ignore anything, `split()` does and in a surprising move there's a difference between Java 7 and Java 8 in its functionality.

Comment: Just those at the end of the list?

Comment: Yes, only the ones at the end. the ones in the middle are kept.